# How to white-space wrap on specific levels?

Tags: css

I have a structure like this:

```
<p>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

If the space is not enough for p to be displayed in one line I want to wrap the text. However, only whole units should be wrapped as one block. I don't want Labels and Values to be split up.

I tried:

```
p > span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
}

p>span>span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: I think what you need is the `word-break: break-word;` style and no need to use `span` inside `p` tag if you use this style for `p` tag.

Comment: And also, it's important to set the width of the `p` tag. Normally, it's `100%` of parent element.

Comment: @Derek.W But then my units get split?

Comment: Do your units have to be inline spans? If you used an `inline-block` element this would be automatic. (Unless you want all of them to wrap if a single one wraps, in which case this gets more complex)

Comment: @DBS I would prefer for them to stay spans but if it is not possible I am open for other solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `white-space: nowrap` on `unit` class, not on `sub-span`.

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.unit {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Label</span>
    <span>Value</span>
  </span>
</p>
```